# I am trying to login to sfdx sample DevHub using git bash, it's giving an error on loging in

Tags: salesforcedx, login-errors, grant-login-access, github

I bypassed the proxy and used this code to log in

`sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a DevHub`

it opens the browser page, I provide the credentials and everytime it gives this error
[image]

and then in the bash it gives this error

`ERROR:  connect ECONNREFUSED 101.53.162.2:443.`

When I logged in the first time, it ran just fine but from the next time it's giving this error. I tried all the ways to login but everytime I get this error.

First time I was abble to make the org default, download sample codes and data from github aswell, but now I get this error.

Can anybody help me out with this??

Comment: Also when I check for the alias list, it shows my logged in id

Comment: The fact that you mention bypassing a proxy makes me think your local network environment is likely an issue here. I don't have any issues connecting to a dev hub via Git Bash. Your local IT or network manager may need to assist.

Comment: @DavidReed But the first time I was able to login to the org and use it. 
[https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli_firewall.htm]

Comment: Also when I try accessing it from my personal machine, I face no trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just like to add that in the Limitations for SalesforceDX in the docs it is stated that

> Limited Support for Shell Environments on Windows Description:
>   Salesforce CLI is tested on the Command Prompt (cmd.exe), Powershell,
>   and Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) for Ubuntu. There are known
>   issues in the cygwin and Min-GW environments. These environments might
>   be tested and supported in a future release. For now, use a supported
>   shell instead. Workaround: None.

git bash is a Min-GW env. We had a developer experience a lot of issues while using so consider using the listed Shell Environments. He as not experienced any issues after moving to Powershell